# Any one have good sample of thread safe call?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I have a function `LoadData` with huge number of WinForm controls and it loads data from database in to the control.
Now it's become very slow, should i use threading, if yes then pls suggest a good sample, I already tried the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)

But it's not useful to me, it'll required lot of change in my code.

Comment: you have to precise what kind of data you are loading, and how; and what you are doing with it

Comment: Also, in general, threading nearly always requires a fair amount of reworking, especially if the core code was designed without threading in mind...

Comment: Your best bet may to look at how much data you load and see if you can't find a way to load a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a lot of code that interacts with UI and you want to do from background thread.

You could add a method like this:

```
private static void UpdateControl(Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
        control.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}
```

The usage:

Old

```
 textBox.Text = "Something";
```

New

```
 UpdateControl(textbox, () => { textBox.Text = "Something" });
```

---

Or extension method, to make usages shorter

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    public static void UpdateControl(this Control control, Action<Control> action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke((Action)(() => action(control)));
        else
            action(control);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
textBox.UpdateControl(arg => arg.Text = "Something");
```

Comment: Very nice concise answer. Prime candidate for an extension method IYAM

Comment: @Alex Aza: if the function has 8/10 controls or may be more than that,then control.InvokeRequired and control.Invoke is executed at same times..?

Comment: @Akhil - not sure I understand. `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` are executed one after another, not at the same time. `control.InvokeRequired` will return true if the call is from non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TPL in .NET 4 to handle this in a potentially simpler manner.  All you need to do is pass around an appropriate `TaskScheduler`.  With a `TaskScheduler` created from the UI context, any call can easily be wrapped into a `Task` that will execute on the UI thread as needed.

For details, see my [blog post on the subject](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/18/parallelism-in-net-part-15-making-tasks-run-the-taskscheduler/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, e) => e.Result = getAllBoxers();
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        var boxers = e.Result as List<Boxer>;
        dgvBoxers.DataSource = boxers;
    };
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Make sure to never do anything that affects the GUI in the `DoWork` because WinForms isn't thread safe.